# Pause game and add flashing text Java

Tags: java

I have this loop

```
    while (true) {
        game.update();
        view.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(DELAY);
    }
```

In the game.update various components of the game have their position changed and those updates are reflected when the repaint() method is called on the view. The view extends JComponent and loops through the game objects and calls their print methods.

What I want to do is have a boolean called `nextLevel` in the game and if it's true Flash text on the screen for the player to notify them that they're going onto the next level. Maybe flash 4-5 times. Then continue the game.
Is this possible? I have been playing around with `Thead.Sleep()` but this only seems to pause the displaying and in the background the game is still going on.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You need to have a "play" and "pause" state which changes when the game gets updated and how it is rendered.  The `sleep` won't change...

Comment: Your game need better internalized management. I suggest devoting a class to game states and data, asset loading, different sprites, input handling, and of course the encompassing window.

Comment: @MadProgrammer how would I go about a play and pause state?

Comment: Create some variable (either an `enum` or `boolean`) in your `game` which is used to determine/set the current state.  Allow the game-loop and `view` to inspect this value and make decisions about what it should do based on it...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to avoid threading by using a `Timer` object.

an example like that could be

```
int flashTimer = 0;
if(nextLevel) {
   Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //flash something method here
       flashTimer++;
   }
   });
   timer.start();
}
```

and then check your `flashTimer` if it reaches the number you want then just stop the timer by `timer.stop();`

Just an idea which seems to me a bit simpler. the 1000 value is milliseconds which is passed and executes the code inside the `actionPerformed` method every 1 sec.

Hope it helped